# Angular design pattern: MVC, MVVM or MV*?

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, design-patterns, mvvm, mv

Angular 1.x (AngularJS) was following more or less the MV* design principle because of its two-way data binding functionality.

Angular2 is adopting a component-based UI, a concept that might be familiar to React developers. In a sense, the Angular 1.x controllers and directives blur into the new Angular 2 Component.

This means that in Angular 2 there are no controllers and no directives. Instead, a component has a selector which corresponds to the html tag that the component will represent and a @View to specify an HTML template for the component to populate.

Angular2 still implements two-way data-binding but does not consist of models for example if I have a `@Component` that displays a list of articles and a `class` that defines the article object:

```
class Article {
title: string;
link: string;
votes: number;

constructor(title: string, link: string, votes?: number){
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.votes = votes || 0;
}
```

This, in the MVC pattern would be considered the model.

So considering this what design pattern does `Angular` follow the closest?

Answer (score 99):

Angular 2 isn't really MVC (but I suppose you can draw parallels). It is Component Based. Let me explain:

Angular 1 is MVC and MVVM (MV*). Angular 1 was groundbreaking for several reasons, but one of the main reasons was because it used Dependency Injection. This was a new concept compared with other JS Frameworks like Backbone and Knockout.

Then React came out and completely transformed front end architecture. It made Front End think more about other options other than MVC and MVVM. Instead it created the idea of Component Based Architecture. This can be regarded as one of the most significant transformation of front-end architecture since HTML & JavaScript.

Angular 2 (and Angular 1.5.x) decided to take React's approach and use Component Based Architecture. However, you can draw slight parallels between MVC, MVVM and Angular 2, which is why I think it can be a little confusing.

Having said this, there are no Controllers or ViewModels in Angular 2 (unless you hand craft them). Instead, there are components, which are made up of a Template (like a view), Classes and MetaData (Decorators).

For example, The Models are the classes that holds the data (eg a data contract to hold data returned by the http service using @angular/http). We can create a new class that adds methods and properties (logic), then merge the Model and the Class. This creates something like a ViewModel. We could then use this ViewModel within our Component.

But to call a Component's Class or a Service a ViewModel or a Controller isn't really correct. The Component contains the Template and the Class. IMO it's a bit like Liskov's Theory - a duck is not a duck - don't try to force the MVC or MVVM pattern into Components as they are different. Think of Angular 2 as Components. But I can see why people would draw parallels to help their initial understanding.

Angular also uses Modules which is part of an upcoming version of JavaScript (ECMAScript 6). This is very powerful because JavaScript has always had problems with Namespaces and Code Organisation. This is where imports and exports come in to components.

Useful links:

https://medium.com/javascript-scene/angular-2-vs-react-the-ultimate-dance-off-60e7dfbc379c

[Is angular2 mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762515/is-angular2-mvc)

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary to assume that the component hierarchy and individual component structure are exclusive, and they aren't in frameworks like Ext JS. Even if Angular isn't MVVM, it was useful for me to think about the view bound component class properties as view model in order to realize implementations as changes in state over time rather than methods or procedural manipulations of the DOM. As with other MVVM frameworks, this helps to reduce spaghetti code and general complexity.

Answer (score 23):

Both Angular 1 & Angular 2 are following MVC (Model, View, Controller) pattern.

In Angular 1, HTML markup is the View, Controller is the Controller & the Service (when it used to retrieve data) is the model.

In Angular 2, template is the View, class is the Controller & the Service (when it used to retrieve data) is the model.

Because Angular is a client side framework, the MVC pattern Angular follows may be called as MVVC (Model, View, View Controller).

Comment: Can explain a bit more why `MVVC`? Thank you.

Comment: The service is not the model. The model is the model. Normally in MVC related frameworks you actually have 2 types of model  (1) The domain model (2) The model that adapts the domain model to the view (sometimes called the ViewModel).

Comment: @gusgorman 
Service is the model in Angular 2+, because it retrieves data, which model is supposed to do in MVC architecture.

Comment: service is not a model, service is just an injectable logic that may or may not retrieve data.

Comment: invalid answer :(

Comment: The service can be used as a model, but it ends up being global state, which is not desired many times.

Answer (score 13):

I am not  too  Keen on using M** notation  (kind of  abused  and foggy).
Anyways in my  opinion the simplest and most effective way to put it is that in Angular2:

the class  (Article in your case) represents the model

the  Component merges view  (in the Template) and controller  (the Typescript logic)

I hope it helps

Answer (score 8):

MVC and MVVM with AngularJS

MVC Design Pattern

To start with, MVC design pattern is not specific to AngularJS, you must have seen/implemented this pattern in many other programming languages.

MVC design pattern can be seen in AngularJS, but before getting into that let’s see what all does MVC design pattern includes:

Model: Model is nothing but data.
View: View represents this data.
Controller: Controller mediates between the two.

In MVC if we make any change in the the view it doesn’t gets updated in model. But in AngularJS, we have heard that there is something called 2-way binding and this 2-way binding enables MVVM design pattern.

MVVM basically includes 3 things:

Model
View
View Model
Controller is actually replaced by View Model in MMVM design pattern. View Model is nothing but a JavaScript function which is again like a controller and is responsible for maintaining relationship between view and model, but the difference here is, if we update anything in view, it gets updated in model, change anything in model, it shows up in view, which is what we call 2-way binding.

This is why we say AngularJS follows MVVM design pattern.

Comment: Wrong: "Model is nothing but data."  In fact, it is data, meta-data, business logic, and database interface.  Wrong: "Controller mediates between the two."  In fact, controller does no such thing.  The view reacts to change events in the model with no prompting from the controller.  The controller's task starts with user events, which you don't even mention.

Comment: the "View Model is nothing but a JavaScript function which is again like a controller" state is wrong

Comment: @GuidoMocha kindly edit and update answers, i like to approve it.

Answer (score 5):

In Angular(excluding version 2 and above) we are using data binding feature. This data binding feature enforces MVVM pattern in ng application because controller in this case causing binding between V&M (changes to view causes change in model and vice versa) So in MVC terminology we can replace 'C' with 'VM' which give 'MVVM'

Answer (score 5):

In my humble opinion you can develop in Angular 2 using MVVM if you want to using some conventions:

1. A component contains the view (the template) and the viewmodel (the class).
2. You only miss the model and you can create it as a normal TypeScript class and pass it to the viewmodel as a constructor parameter.

The technology is pretty similar to the one available in PRISM and WPF and there you develop everything using MVVM (if you want to).