# AngularJS - client side MVC - Where to place "Model" in directory structure

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, mvvm, model

As we know , AngularJS follows MVC pattern(more correctly MV*) . 
We usually create different directories for each layer . eg ., controller JS will be "**controllers**" and view will be normally in "**html**" directory .
(controllers will work with service classes to get the data from server . We use to place service request JS in  "**services**" folder)

But , we usually don't have separate directory for "Model" classes .
Can someone provide a simple example for "Model" directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

**The Model**
The model is responsible for managing application data. It responds to the request from view and to the instructions from controller to update itself.

**The View**
A presentation of data in a particular format, triggered by the controller's decision to present the data.

**The Controller**
The controller responds to user input and performs interactions on the data model objects. The controller receives input, validates it, and then performs business operations that modify the state of the data model.

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1):

Working on an angularjs based project I structure the front end the following way:

```
|wwwroot
    |Js
      |signup
        |signupCtrl.js
        |signupSrvc.js
      |login
        |loginCtrl.js
        |loginSrvc.js
      |dashboard 
        |dashboardCtrl.js
        |dashboardSrvc.js
    |templates
      |signup.html
      |login.html
      |dashboard.html
    app.js
    run.js
    routes.js
    index.html
```

Understanding that some people consider the model, the place "where you hold data returned by the http service using @angular/http", according to the post [Angular2: MVC, MVVM or MV*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950582/angular2-mvc-mvvm-or-mv)

Then maybe this previous structure may help you having an approach. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When we say `modal` in angularJS, we are talking about the data that is being transferred from `html` pages to `controller`. Now, in general there is no standard architecture design to create a `modal` folder inside.

Reason being, the JS are not strongly typed language so it was not a straightforward way to implement as we can now do in `Angular` using `typescript` (which is **strongly typed**).

If you want to create a `modal` directory, you can create a JS `classes` and accordingly use it inside controllers.But as I said before, it will be your own personal choice. Normally we don't create a `modal` js files in `angularJS`.

Answer (score 0):

Modal is nothing but data. Whatever we are assigning the values to a scope variable to render in the view(html) is modal. So no need of separate directory for that and also it not a recommended approach.