# How to break ngFor loop in typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm developing Hybrid app using `Ionic-3`. I'm trying to call function from `Html` and get some values return from `typescript` with this function but i see the function is call multiple times and my browser and application is hang. My html and typescript function is below.

> HTML

```
  <div *ngFor="let product of myCourier">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6> Charge</ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>Rs. {{getcharge(product)}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>
```

> Typescript

```
   getcharge(item){
    var dat: { [k: string]: any } = {};
    dat.toaddress = item.to_address
    dat.fromaddress = item.from_address
    this.httpClient.post(this.config.url + 'getrate.php', dat).subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data.ResponseCode == 1) {
        var charge = data.charge
        console.log(charge)
        return charge
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It is not good practice to use a function that do an http request in a template.
I suggest you too get all your data from server before to display them.

Answer (score 0):

As best practices, you shouldn't add logic inside the view.

For your case, you should rewrite your for something like this:

> Your HTML (No function call, just `product`)

```
<div *ngFor="let product of myCourierProducts">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6> Charge</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>Rs. {{product}}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

> Your TS

```
ngOnInit() { // Or wherever you set your myCourier variable
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        myCourier[i] = SOMETHING
        myCourierProducts[i] = getcharge(SOMETHING)
    }
}

getcharge(item){
    var dat: { [k: string]: any } = {};
    dat.toaddress = item.to_address
    dat.fromaddress = item.from_address
    this.httpClient.post(this.config.url + 'getrate.php', dat).subscribe((data: any) => {
        if (data.ResponseCode == 1) {
            var charge = data.charge
            console.log(charge)
            return charge
        }
    });
}
```

It is important to mention that the `component` ("Model"), in the [MVVM Angular architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950582/angular2-mvc-mvvm-or-mv) is not for complex logic, it is for small logic directed to the View.

The complex logic should be placed inside `services`.

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/