# Flux vs MVC Design Pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, flux

I'm beginning to learn flux design pattern and I feel like flux isn't much different from MVC. Controllers are combined into one dispatcher, but with nested components can't the same be achieved, where the main component is the dispatcher.  So what makes flux so special?

I've been looking at these three examples and in the stackoverflow link, theres a flux chart where the model directly updates the view instead of going to the controller but why does that make it special*?

[MVC vs. Flux ? Bidirectional vs. Unidirectional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447710/mvc-vs-flux-bidirectional-vs-unidirectional)

https://medium.com/hacking-and-gonzo/flux-vs-mvc-design-patterns-57b28c0f71b7#.h2neiy70j

http://fluxxor.com/what-is-flux.html

Comment: Who says one is better than the other, especially in everything? Otherwise this is a very broad question.

Comment: Fb says its better :).  changed better to special.  I just want to know, what benefits flux has than mvc like angular.